# Angular validation issues with complex model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

My setup: **Angular 1.4.4**

I have simple form that looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl3">
  <datepick ng-model="model.carA" foo3="model.carB"></datepick>

  <datepick ng-model="model.carB" foo3="model.carA"></datepick>
  <pre> {{ model | json }} </pre>
</div>
```

`datepick` directive looks like this:

```
myApp.directive('datepick', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '='
    },
    template: '<div ng-if="true"><input type="text" ng-model="ngModel.bar"/></div>'
  };
});
```

So I pass object with property `bar` to it using `ng-model` attribute. Till now everything works as expected. Model is synced with changes in rendered form.

Next step I want to introduce validation to validate property `bar` on underlying model for current directive with some other object in the MyCtrl3 - `model` . I've created attribute directive `foo3` for this purpose:

```
myApp.directive('foo3', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {

      scope.$watch(attrs.foo3, function(newValue, oldValue) {
        // New Value of comparison field
        console.log("New valued for comparison model: " + JSON.stringify(newValue));
        // Current value of undelying movelValue
        console.log("Current value for undelying model" + JSON.stringify(controller.$modelValue));

        controller.$validate();
      }, true);

      var validateMoreThanDate = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        let viewValueObject = modelValue;
        var comparisonModel = scope.$eval(attr.moreThanDateObject);

        if ((!viewValueObject && !viewValueObject.bar) ||
          (!comparisonModel && !comparisonModel.bar)) {
          // It's valid because we have nothing to compare against
          return true;
        }
        // It's valid if model is lower than the model we're comparing against
        return viewValueObject.bar > comparisonModel.bar;
      };

      controller.$validators['moreThanDateObject'] = validateMoreThanDate;
    }
  };
});
```

As you can see I'm passing model for comparison as argument to directive `foo3`. Watchers track every change, but validators are not triggered when model changes.

**Question:** How can I validate thos fields in my case? (Here is working jsFiddle to inspect live code: https://jsfiddle.net/ichyr/b1jqfkj1/)

**N.B.** I know that $parsers and $formatters pipeline are not triggered when the model in object and the property of this object changes:

> If the new value is an object (rather than a string or a number), we
>   should make a copy of the object before passing it to $setViewValue.
>   This is because ngModel does not perform a deep watch of objects, it
>   only looks for a change of identity. If you only change the property
>   of the object then ngModel will not realise that the object has
>   changed and will not invoke the $parsers and $validators pipelines.

So maybe $validators are also not triggered, but addition of `controller.$validate()` didn't helped in the $watch expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**N.B.** Collegue of mine proposed better way for doing this.

This solution can be improved. We can use artificial object inside `datepick` directive with custom getter/setter functions to omit usage of `$watchers` there like this:

```
myApp.directive('datepick', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '='
    },
    template: '<div ng-if="model.open"><input type="text" ng-model="model.value"/></div>',
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.model = {
        get value() {
          return scope.ngModel;
        },
        set value(newValue) {
          scope.ngModel = parseInt(newValue);
        },
        open: true
      };
    }
  };
});
```

This overcomes the shaddowing of variables in `ng-if` scope as we pass object there, not primitive.

This way introduces the following benefits:

1. removes the need to pass object to `datepick` directive
2. removed few `$watch` expressions as we're levereging native JS functionlity (thus improves performance)
3. enables to use primitives as arguments (model) to `datepicker` that enables to leverage angular.js **$parsers**, **$formatters** or **$validators** (they don't work / detect changes in object properties/ if the model is object)
4. getters and setters not may be used in place of angular **$parsers** and **$formatters**

You may find the resulting fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ichyr/suncp2gf/

Answer (score 0):

I've successeded with this task using **$watch**ers without doing any $parsers, $formatters or $validators. First two definately doesn't work with complex models if the properties changes. Last one seems not to work also.

I've created a two watches for both models I'm referencing in the `datepick` directive via `ng-model` and `foo3` + created small validation function. So `foo3` validation attribute directive now looks like this:

```
myApp.directive('foo3', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {

      scope.$watch(attrs.foo3, function(newValue, oldValue) {
                var isValid = validateMoreThanDate(controller.$modelValue, newValue);
        controller.$setValidity('moreThanDateObject', isValid);
      }, true);

       scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue, oldValue) {
                var isValid = validateMoreThanDate(newValue, scope.$eval(attrs.foo3));
        controller.$setValidity('moreThanDateObject', isValid);
      }, true);

      var validateMoreThanDate = function(underlyingModel, comparisonModel) {
        if ((!underlyingModel && !underlyingModel.bar) ||
          (!comparisonModel && !comparisonModel.bar)) {
          // It's valid because we have nothing to compare against
          return true;
        }
        // It's valid if model is lower than the model we're comparing against
        return underlyingModel.bar > comparisonModel.bar;
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Also I've create a small decoration directive for formatting and parsing the the value in the inputs inself (test type resulted in string values):

```
// Directive to format the data in the text inputs
myApp.directive('numberInputParser', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
      debugger;
      controller.$parsers.unshift(function(data) {
        return parseInt(data);
      });

      controller.$formatters.unshift(function(data) {
        debugger;
        return data;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

And the code for `datepick` directive respectfully changed (added `number-input-parser` directive):

```
myApp.directive('datepick', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '='
    },
    template: '<div ng-if="true"><input type="text" ng-model="ngModel.bar" number-input-parser/></div>'
  };
});
```

Resulting code can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/ichyr/f1qeey37/